# UVM-SystemC MACOSX make error

Tags: macos, makefile, uvm, systemc

I'm trying to run uvm-systemc on macosx. Link to download: http://accellera.org/images/downloads/drafts-review/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1.tar.gz

In the install flow, ../configure works fine, but on make i get this error:

```
Making all in macros
  CCLD   libmacros.la
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[4]: *** [libmacros.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I've looked online, and it seems that it is a makefile problem. However the uvm-systemc makefile is way to complex for me to comprehend where the issue could reside. Any ideas on why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the libtool being executed to create a library file without a cpp file .
The tlm1 directory (and macros directory) do not have any .cpp file , hence there is no need to call the libtool in the respective makefiles.

As the UVM-SystemC for Mac OS is not in the list of tested OS you MAY run a few more issues. 
I ran into 3 issues ( including the one mentioned above ). workaround to those are provided below .

The OS version  for which the installation was completed.

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.4
BuildVersion:   15E65
```

1)

command :

step 1

```
../configure --with-systemc=[systemC-Base]/systemc-2.3.1
```

step 2 :

[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir/  make

### Error:

```
Making all in macros
  CCLD   libmacros.la
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[4]: *** [libmacros.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make:  [all-recursive] Error 1
```

---

Fix :

---

changes to 2 files

[ objdir - is the run temporary directory for the make script ]

[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir/src/uvmsc/tlm1/Makefile - 
  comment out the libtool run.

line 314

```
#       $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK)  $(libtlm1_la_OBJECTS) $(libtlm1_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir/src/uvmsc/macros/Makefile

line 311

```
  #       $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK)  $(libmacros_la_OBJECTS) $(libmacros_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

OR

```
  [ for this you have to re-run  
 ../configure --with-systemc=[systemC-Base]/systemc-2.3.1 
   so that it can recreated the 
 <base>/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir/src/uvmsc/tlm1/Makefile
 and the 
  [base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir/src/uvmsc/macros/Makefile ]
```

comment out the libtool run in the base file.

[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/src/uvmsc/tlm1/Makefile.in

line 314

```
#       $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK)  $(libtlm1_la_OBJECTS) $(libtlm1_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/src/uvmsc/macros/Makefile

line 311

```
  #       $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK)  $(libmacros_la_OBJECTS) $(libmacros_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

———————————

2)

Command :
   make install

Error :

/bin/sh: ../../../config/install-sh: Permission denied

Fix :

```
 [[base]/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/objdir]  chmod +x   ../config/install-sh
```

3)

Command:

make check

### Error :

[systemC-base]/systemc-2.3.1/include/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h:32:3: note: constrained by private inheritance here
  private virtual tlm_put_if< PUT_DATA > ,

[systemC-base]/systemc-2.3.1/include/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h:87:7: error: inherited virtual base class 'tlm_blocking_get_if' has private destructor
class tlm_master_imp :

[systemC-base]/systemc-2.3.1/include/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h:33:3: note: constrained by private inheritance here
  private  virtual tlm_get_peek_if< GET_DATA >
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[systemc-base]/systemc-2.3.1/include/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h:87:7: error: inherited virtual base class 'tlm_nonblocking_get_if' has private destructor

—————————

Fix :

———————————

This seems like a compiler related issue. MAYBE in some platforms this is okay but it failed for this platform. 
To fix this the source file of the systemC installation needs to be updated. 
You can update the source file and re-install - gmake install (systemC) 
or just update the include file.

[systemC-base]/systemc-2.3.1/**src**/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h

[systemC-Base]/obj/  - gmake install

OR

[systemC-base]/systemc-2.3.1/**include**/tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_req_rsp_channels/tlm_put_get_imp.h

change line 31,32

```
class tlm_put_get_imp :    
  private virtual tlm_put_if< PUT_DATA > ,    
  public  virtual tlm_get_peek_if< GET_DATA > // change from  private to public - private fails
```

change line  86,87

```
class tlm_master_imp :
  private tlm_put_get_imp< REQ , RSP > ,
  public virtual tlm_master_if< REQ , RSP > // change from  private to public - private fails
```

Comment: Thank You very much Rahul. This worked for me. I'll also post a link to this thread in the UVM-SystemC forums.

Comment: That's great , Thanks Masab

Comment: Hi again Rahul, it seems that I do need the library files (libmacosx-64). But this folder has not been created in the UVM directory. Is there any workaround this? I do need this folder to include in a separate Makefile for a software that I am using.

Comment: Hi Masab , i can see a <base_dir>/uvm/uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1/lib-macosx64  in my uvm installation . Is this the one you are referring to ? If not could you give me more details

Comment: Thank You again. I didn't do make again after changing some of the files (I directly jumped to make install).